# Would manga fall within POCSO, section 15?

Tags: india, definition, interpretation, sexual-offences, child-porn

[Section 15](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_13_14_00005_201232_1517807323686&sectionId=12864&sectionno=15&orderno=15) Protection of Children from Sexual Offences Act, 2012 includes this:

> Any person, who stores or possesses pornographic material in any form involving a child for commercial purpose shall be punished on the first conviction with imprisonment of either description which shall not be less than three years which may extend to five years, or with fine, or with both and in the event of second or subsequent conviction, with imprisonment of either description which shall not be less than five years which may extend to seven years and shall also be liable to fine.

Storing and possessing includes viewing and browsing it too or having it in your browser history.

In India there are online communities that reccomend and share links and advertise for sale various manga which involves various sexually explicit content involving child characters (large amount of manga are like this) and some of those sites have advertisements running on them too. would they be liable under this law?

Answer (score 2):

No

[Manga are comics or graphic novels](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manga) so do not meet the definition of child pornography at [section 2(1)(da)](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_13_14_00005_201232_1517807323686&orderno=2), POCSO

> "child pornography" means any visual depiction of sexually explicit conduct involving a child which include photograph, video, digital or computer generated image **indistinguishable from an actual child** and image created, adapted, or modified, but **appear to depict a child**
>
> [*my emboldenment*]